# What's the best way to import Flask config to a non-Flask script?

Tags: python, flask, code-organization

I'm developing a Flask project, along with a command-line ([Click](http://click.palletsprojects.com/)-powered) helper script to populate/export from the database.

I'm using Flask's `instance/config.py` to set parameters like database credentials, etc. And I also have a default config to use as fallback

My question is: what's the best way to import these settings to my command-line script? The options I can think of are:

- Import `app.config` and use settings from there
- Import settings directly from `config.py`

A direct import will be cleaner, since it won't have to unnecessarily import the whole app; however it will mean having to replicate the work of discovering where the config files are, importing them in the right order, etc. (And if I change the way config is imported, I'd have to update it in both).

Right now I have the whole Flask code, views and all, in `app.py`...so another option may be to move those out, and have a minimal `app.py`that just has the config and nothing else.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score -2):

Don't know much but all I know is that at the end of nonserver running flask application we have to use

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
with app.app_context():
    main()
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. I know how to run the Flask app; my question is about how to import the app's `config` into a related non-Flask script